# Computed property is not being updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a data property, which is an empty array:

```
data: () => ({
    total: [],
});
```

A method called `getAmount()`:

```
getAmount(item){ // gets individual amount and pushes it to the total array
    var amount = 0;
    // Skipping the amount calculation to keep the 
    // question as small as possible
    amount = item.price + 10;
    this.total[this.total.length] = amount;
    return amount;
}
```

And a computed property called `getTotal()`:

```
getTotal(){
    if(this.total.length > 0){
      return this.total.reduce((x,y) => x+y);
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  },
```

In the template I am accessing the getAmount() method and getTotal computed property like this:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="orderShares"
  hide-actions
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.order.order_code }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ getAmount(props.item) }}</td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>

<p> Total Amount: {{ getTotal }} </p>
```

The total amount always remains `0`. But what I was expecting is that it should update as many times as the `getAmount()` method is called. Because `getAmount()` triggers a change in the `total` prop, theoretically, computed property `getTotal` should also be updated since it depends on `total`. But that's not what's happening here. How can I fix this?

Comment: `0+0` is still `0`. What exactly do you expect the amount to change to?

Comment: Your getAmoun boils down to this.total[0] = 0

Comment: Please read the comment inside the snippet. It was intended for you:
`// Skipping the amount calculation to keep the 
    // question as small as possible`

Comment: It's only ever going to access the 0th index

Comment: just an fyi for what I think is tidier code -... `getTotal() { return this.total.reduce((x,y) => x+y, 0); }` - no if/else required ... also `this.total.push(amount)` is identical to `this.total[this.total.length] = amount;` - again, not your problem ... isn't the data property a function, not an empty array as you state?

Comment: can you `console.log(this.total.length)` just to see that it is indeed increasing? if, for some reason, this.total is **not** an array, then you will see exactly what you get

Comment: Can this be related to computed caching? Try using `getTotal()` as a method instead of a computed property and use it on template `{{getTotal()}}`. [Read it in the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

Comment: @JaromandaX, When I said `a data property` I was actually referring to the only data property inside the data object, which is: `total`. Also, I inspected `total` not with your console.log approach, but with the Vue Devtools and it was indeed increasing.

Comment: and it is an array that is growing, correct? (sorry, my `vue` is rusty(

Comment: @AmmoPT `getTotal` is supposed to be re-evaluated every time the `getAmount()` is triggered. `getTotal` depends on the returned value (`amount`) of `getAmount()`

Comment: I have a feeling that the computed property is not being updated because I am using `this.total[this.total.length]` instead of `push()`. And I cannot use `push()` because it then warns me about infinite loop issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to do this in your method instead due to array detection caveats (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

```
this.total.push(amount)
```

Also, that `getTotal` computed can simply be:

```
return this.total.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)
```

Comment: Vue won't let me use `push()` on `total`. It will throw an warning: `[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`

Comment: Vue is letting you use it. It's just you have infinite loop in your logic. This will likely fix your problem once you figure out why that loop is happening. It is kind of confusing you're setting something in a function that starts with `get`. Would need to see more.

Comment: I updated the question with my templating logic. Could you please help me point out what I've done wrong? I am using Vuetify, if that helps.

Comment: Could this be a problem that I am calling `getAmount()` (should've named `getAmountAndUpdateTotal`) within the template?

Comment: Yes. That is definitely a problem. I wouldn't update `total` there at all. Ideally you'd go through `orderShares` and calculate the total from that and getAmount only does things for presentation.

Comment: getAmount likely gets called a *lot* more than you think.

Comment: Yes Bill, I just checked with a console.log('called') and it was called about 23x times. I am shocked!

Comment: I cannot go through `orderShares` and calculate `total` from there, because `total` depends on the `amount` retrieved from `getAmount()`. What can I do?

Comment: It seems like the amount returned by `getAmount` should come from a computed as well. You might want something like `orderSharesWithAmount` so you don't need to use that method to get the amount.

Comment: `this.orderItems.map(orderItem => ({ ...orderItem, amount: orderITem + 10 }))` and so on.